# Is it wrong export React Hooks to manage global state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am exporting the return of a Hook which I use in the root component of a project. Then it becomes very easy for the other components to import globalState and setGlobalState ().

I did several tests here and it worked very well. The problem is that I have not seen anyone in the community using it in the same way.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Level2 from "./components/Level2";

export let setGlobalState = () => {};
export let globalState = {};

const initalState = { counter: 0 };

const App = () => {
  [globalState, setGlobalState] = useState(initalState);
  return (
    <>
      <Level2 />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Is it wrong to manage global state in that way? If it is, why?

Here I have a repository with the whole project:
https://github.com/andregardi/global-state-with-hooks

Comment: Where are you using that in your codebase? You are never reassigning setGlobalState/globalState so they would only ever be the default assignments. The ones in your `App` component have no bearing on the exports except for having shadowed variable names. The only way to make global state would kind of like that using default React apis would be to use a context that wraps your component tree.

Comment: It seems to be working https://codesandbox.io/s/github/andregardi/global-state-with-hooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach has some issues with updates. Only children of the `App` component can react to global state changes. Those children still might not get rerendered if something in the tree blocks an update (`PureComponent`, `React.memo`, etc.)

Also `setGlobalState` might get redefined by some module.

Check this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/n5ow7lxjvl?fontsize=14) to observe the issue. All components will update the global state but the "broken" one will not react to updates because its props don't change.

Comment: Brilliant answer!

Comment: The example you provided, really helped me to better understand.
Actually I rewrite it. If it is not too much much to ask, can you tell me if this new approach solves the problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/zwjnv87y5m

(I would clean up the listener array with useEffects in a real life app)

Comment: It would be easier to have `globalState` and `setGlobalState` inside a context and `useContext` instead of `useGlobal`. Same results with less coding. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Answer (score 0):

It  is not very correct to define states globally then mutating them because multiple instances of same component might need to have their own state and not share it. If you define the state globally all of them will share the same state and it will lead to inconsistencies

DEMO

```js
const { useState } = React;
let initialState = 0;
let globalState;
let setGlobalState;

function Counter () {
   [globalState, setGlobalState] = useState(initialState);
   return (
      <div>
         <div>Count: {globalState}</div>
         <button onClick={() => setGlobalState(count => count + 1)}>Increment</button>
      </div>
   )
}

function App() {
   return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>Counter 1: </div>
          <Counter />
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>Counter 2: </div>
          <Counter />
        </div>
      </div>
   )
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```